# When i try to open archive pages i get a 404 error

Tags: archives

i do not create any new CPT, simply want to open WP standard archive pages like category (eg. https://museosangennaro.it/category/eventi), but when i try to do that i got a 404 error.

Can you help me?

Comment: What does your permalink setup look like?

Comment: Also, what does your `.htaccess` file look like? Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/346117/edit) to answer the relevant questions.

Comment: Thanks to all. I did a check on premalink setup and .htaccess and everything seems to be fine. Solved with the @T.Todua's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you have to go to `Permalinks > click "Save Permalinks"` and refresh that archive page to see if it solved.

If not, then maybe you are using some plugin that caused the problem? deactivate all plugins and re-save permalinks and check that archive page again.

Comment: Hi  @T.Todua, i tried with permalinks reset but nothing happened. Solved by disabling all plug-ins and by checking one by one. Finally it was a wrong setting in Polylang plugin. Thank you for your support